# Is it safe to delete "/crypto_keyfile.bin"?

Tags: boot, lubuntu, encryption, luks, secure-boot

I use Lubuntu 20.04 with full-disk encryption.

```
# lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Each time I boot, there is a one line login to enter the pass-phrase.

Then, I check the key using `cryptsetup` and check which slot that being used.

```
# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda2 | grep ENABLE
Key Slot 0: ENABLED
Key Slot 1: ENABLED
```

I see there is `/crypto_keyfile.bin` in the root directory. When, I test to open it:

```
# cryptsetup open --key-file /crypto_keyfile.bin --test-passphrase /dev/sda2 --verbose
Key slot 1 unlocked.
Command successful.
```

It seem the file use slot number 1, not slot number 0 which is being use for my boot time pass-phrase.

Based on [this documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dm-crypt/Device_encryption):

> It may be useful to apply when using the GRUB early cryptodisk
> feature, in order to avoid ***entering two passphrases*** during boot.

My question is, is it safe to delete "/crypto_keyfile.bin"? If so, will it ask the second pass-phrase when the file is missing or even corrupt?

Thank you.

Comment: Disclaimer: I do not use Lubuntu. Take this comment with a grain of salt. ⇢ 30 years of experience with encryption has taught me many things, one of which being “don’t mess with things”. The file you speak of is measured in bytes. Why delete it? Does it interfere with the boot process? Or is this a cosmetic activity? If it ain’t broke, don’t poke it …

Comment: @matigo: I just curious what if that happened, so, I can have plans if such bad thing occurred. Of course I already backup the file in the secure location.

Comment: You are about to shoot yourself in the foot. Why would you want to delete that file if you quite obviously have no clue what it is?

Comment: @HuHa: That is why I ask about it. Besides that, I might be able to use slot number 1 for other purposes.

Comment: I have no idea... but if I was curious like you seem to be, I'd just test it and see. I wouldn't test it on a box I value, but use a spare box (as I do QA-testing, I'd use a recent QA-test install for 20.04.3, or *impish* as those are what I'll have handy) or just test using a VM; installing/creating one if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

I read the manual and what I did was to run:

`sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda2 --key-file /crypto_keyfile.bin`

And then deleted the file.

**CAUTION**: only do this if you already tested your slot 0 with:

`sudo cryptsetup open --test-passphrase /dev/sda2 --verbose` and entering your passphrase to see that you can still unlock the device before removing and deleting the key file.

Also, keep in mind that this file is normally created to automatically unlock the PC, if you remove this it will no longer do it. normally dracut of mkinitcpio will pick this file up and use it to unlock devices.